# Joomla Subform field

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

We have inherited a Joomla project and need to implement a repeating field for product images.

We're having trouble understanding how to implement this in the database. Is there some naming convention to tell Joomla what table/foreign keys to use?

We've got this in the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<field
    name="gallery_images"
    type="subform"
    label="Gallery Images"
    description="Images for the gallery"
    multiple="true"
    min="1"
    max="10"
    >
    <form>
        <field
            name="image_url"
            type="media"
            label="Image"
            />
    </form>
</field>
```

Then we have the is pulled into the form edit.php file like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('gallery_images'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('gallery_images'); ?></div>
</div>
```

This actually all works perfectly on the backend end. But it doesn't save any where. We have tried making a field on the products table thinking maybe it would store as JSON. We've tried created another table for the images with a product_id on it thinking maybe Joomla just works out the foreign key?

The Joomla documentation doesn't seem to say anything about how it works in the DB. (https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way it is configured now, Joomla will attempt to store the subfields-json in the respective models `gallery_images` column. There only are naming conventions concerning the file names, but since your edit.php already renders your .xml files fields, I would assume that is correct.

Comment: Thanks, that's what we expected but it didn't happen. Possibly there is something else we were doing which stopped it? Either way, we wrote some code to manually save the field and that worked. We found other people on the internet who had to do the same thing. I've added the answer.

Comment: It is possible that the media field needs extra care since it is a javascript heavy field and the subform does have issues with fields that require javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since the gallery_images field was being saved into by joomla, we wrote some code to do this manually.

```
class ModelProduct extends JModelAdmin
{
    public function save($data) {
        if (parent::save($data)) {
            $registry = new Registry;
            $registry->loadArray($data['gallery_image']);
            $data['gallery_image'] = (string) $registry;
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            // Fields to update.
            $fields = array(
                $db->quoteName('gallery_image') . ' = ' . $db->quote($data['gallery_image']),
            );

            // Conditions for which records should be updated.
            $conditions = array(
                $db->quoteName('id') . ' = '.$data['id'],
            );

            $query->update($db->quoteName('v4yn2_product'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $result = $db->execute();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```